# Redirect all resources (exe | dll | conf) from bin\Release to a common output folder

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, msbuild-task, azure-devops-extensions

I'm wondering if there is any MSBuild feature that allows us to redirect all resources (exe | dll | conf) from bin\Release to a common output folder for all projects based on Directory.build.propos / Directory.build.target.

Actually, I'm using the Azure DevOps pipeline task “copy files” but I'm not satisfied with the results because it copies some, 25000 files and the operation took 10 minutes.

Comment: Hi @Mselmi, could the answer help to meet your requirement? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Mselmi, have you try following answer? Will appreciate if you could tell whether it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Override the value of the `OutDir` property. This property is used in each project. The outputs of each project will be written to the `OutDir`. By overriding you can set the `OutDir` of all the projects to the common output folder, saving the time of making copies.

Create a `Directory.build.props` file in a folder that is a parent of all your project folders. In the `Directory.build.props` file, set a value for `OutDir` for a shared folder. You can conditionalize the property to be set only for Azure DevOps pipeline builds by testing for the `TF_BUILD` variable. `TF_BUILD` will exist and have a value of 'true' in a pipeline build.

e.g.

```xml
<!-- Directory.build.props -->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TF_Build)' != '' and '$(TF_Build)'">
     <OutDir>$([MSBuild]::EnsureTrailingSlash('$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'))sharedOutput</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

If there are already `Directory.build.props` files (and/or `Directory.build.targets` files), you can add an import at the beginning of each file to ensure the complete chain of files up the directory hierarchy is included.

e.g.

```xml
<!-- Directory.build.props -->
<Project>
  <Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('$(MSBuildThisFile)', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../'))" />

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TF_Build)' != '' and '$(TF_Build)'">
     <OutDir>$([MSBuild]::EnsureTrailingSlash('$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'))sharedOutput</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```